# PHP Get All Price IDs in URL

Tags: php, url, get

This is probably an easy solution but I'm drawing a blank. I'm trying to create a PHP filter based on values such as $, $$, $$$, $$$$, and $$$$$. I would like to be able to select more than price and have it filter. My SQL table looks like:

price_id price_name

1           $

2           $$

3           $$$

4           $$$$

5           $$$$$

My url looks like www.example.com/search.php?address=567&price_id=1&price_id=2. When I enter the GET below, I am able to get the last price price_id=2 but not price_id=1. Am I able to get both price_ids from the URL and how?

`$price_id = $_GET['price_id'];
echo ''.$price_id.'';`

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is not doing it automatically for you because all the variables have the same name: `price_id=1` gets overwritten by `price_id=2`.  There are two ways around this:

If you don't control the URL, can do it manually by using then `explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])`.

Alternatively, if you have control of the URL being generated, just put square brackets on the end: `price_id[]=1&price_id[]=2`

Answer (score 0):

```
 www.example.com/search.php?address=567&price_id=1&price_id=2
```

change this into

```
 www.example.com/search.php?address=567&price_id1=1&price_id2=2
```

then

do

```
$price_id1 = $_GET['price_id1'];
$price_id2 = $_GET['price_id2'];

echo ''.$price_id1.''.$price_id2;
```

try and tell

Comment: why are you prefixing and appending empty strings?

Comment: sorry i didnt understand i m beginner to myself i would love to know to do it better :)

Comment: no problem, '' is a empty string. And `.` concates two strings. So your example is the same as $price_id1 . $price_id2

Answer (score 0):

Make price_id and array `[]`:

```
search.php?address=567&price_id[]=1&price_id[]=2
```

Then you have `$_GET['price_id'][0]` and `$_GET['price_id'][1]`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't have pass the same parameter twice. It would be like declaring $value = 1; $value = 2 and then trying to read 1 and 2 from value, if that makes sense. You can fix this by putting a special character in between the values in the price_id. Something like price_id=1*2 or you could simply start at price_id and then for each new id you could increment it to be price_id1, price_id2, etc. I like the first because you can explode it and not have to check if other ones are set, but it's all preference.

Answer (score 0):

You get the second price because both have the same id, Try using post
i.e

```
<form method="post" action ="act.php">
<input name=price[1]>
<input name=price[2]>
</form>

And get the values using post
//act.php
$prices = $_POST['price'];
```